# Why my Array is a empty after .then()? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I wrote a controller and I do not understand why in the method then my array is correct and I need to send it, and for .then () my array is empty. I can not send a res in the middle of the loop.

```
exports.getRecipientdata = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.recipientId;
  const sendersArray = [];
  Transaction.findAll({
    where: {
      id_recipient: userId,
    },
  }).then(transactions => {
    for (let i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
      User.findOne({
        where: {
          id: transactions[i].id_sender,
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'name', 'surname'],
        include: [
          {
            model: Transaction,
            where: { id_sender: db.Sequelize.col('user.id') },
            attributes: [
              'amount_money',
              'date_time',
              'transfer_title',
              'id_recipient',
              'id_sender',
            ],
          },
        ],
      })
        .then(sender => {
          sendersArray.push(sender);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(sendersArray)); // ok
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
    console.log('sendersArray', sendersArray); // empty?
    res.send(sendersArray);
  });
};
```

Comment: Well, thats because the empty console message is executed before you actually get async result and update the senders array. Don't forget that you code is asyncronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is sending out requests which *asynchronously* populate `sendersArray`. If you `console.log(sendersArray)` *synchronously* after the `for` loop has run, it won't have been populated yet. Instead of a `for` loop, use `.map` and `Promise.all` to wait for all requests to complete:

```
exports.getRecipientdata = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.recipientId;
  const sendersArray = [];
  Transaction.findAll({
    where: {
      id_recipient: userId,
    },
  }).then(transactions => {
    return Promise.all(transactions.map(({ id_sender }) => (
      User.findOne({
        where: {
          id: id_sender,
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'name', 'surname'],
        include: [
          {
            model: Transaction,
            where: { id_sender: db.Sequelize.col('user.id') },
            attributes: [
              'amount_money',
              'date_time',
              'transfer_title',
              'id_recipient',
              'id_sender',
            ],
          },
        ],
      })
        .then(sender => {
          sendersArray.push(sender);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    )));
  })
  .then(() => {
    res.send(sendersArray);
  });
};
```

Another possibility, rather than `push`ing to an outer variable, would be to use the array created by `Promise.all`, and filter by boolean to remove the falsey values (since the `catch`'s lack of a return value will have resulted in `undefined`s being present in the result of the `Promise.all` array):

```
exports.getRecipientdata = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.recipientId;
  Transaction.findAll({
    where: {
      id_recipient: userId,
    },
  }).then(transactions => {
    return Promise.all(transactions.map(({ id_sender }) => (
      User.findOne({
        where: {
          id: id_sender,
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'name', 'surname'],
        include: [
          {
            model: Transaction,
            where: { id_sender: db.Sequelize.col('user.id') },
            attributes: [
              'amount_money',
              'date_time',
              'transfer_title',
              'id_recipient',
              'id_sender',
            ],
          },
        ],
      })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    )));
  })
  .then((sendersArray) => {
    res.send(sendersArray.filter(Boolean));
  });
};
```